# How to fix error No signature of method: build_cn6um2j93z7api7ukyico1vjp.android()

Tags: android, android-studio

ERROR:No signature of method: build_cn6um2j93z7api7ukyico1vjp.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_cn6um2j93z7api7ukyico1vjp$_run_closure1) values: [build_cn6um2j93z7api7ukyico1vjp$_run_closure1@a8565de]
Build gradle:

```
 plugins {
       id 'com.android.application'
            }

      android {
          compileSdkVersion 30
          buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabeld true
        applicationId "com.example.ahorasifotos"
       minSdkVersion 16
       targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
       
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
   implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.3'
   implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
   androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `checkDependencies` to `false`:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        checkDependencies false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```